# Javascript (object.innerhtml) is not compatible with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I have created a script that changes the combo boxes based on the category chosen. The problem is that the script works in all other browsers aside from Internet Explorer (version 7+). I am not getting an error message, which indicates that IE doesn't like the object.innerhtml. What can I do to solve this?

Working Example: http://adcabinetsales.com/style-chooser.html

```
function ChangeCabinetCollection() {
    if (document.getElementById("cabinet_collection").value == "broughton") {
        // COPY VALUES
        var first = document.getElementById('broughton_styles');
        var options = first.innerHTML;
        var second = document.getElementById('cabinet_selector');

        // REPLACE VALUES
        second.innerHTML = options;

        // CHANGE CABINET IMAGE TO BE IN THE COLLECTION OF CHOICE
        changeDoor("cabinet_selector");
    } else if (document.getElementById("cabinet_collection").value == "specialty") {
        // COPY VALUES
        var first = document.getElementById('cabinet_style');
        var options = first.innerHTML;
        var second = document.getElementById('cabinet_selector');

        // REPLACE VALUES
        second.innerHTML = options;

        // CHANGE CABINET IMAGE TO BE IN THE COLLECTION OF CHOICE
        changeDoor("cabinet_selector");
    }
}

function ChangeGraniteCollection() {
    if (document.getElementById("granite_collection").value == "new_arrivals") {
        // COPY VALUES
        var first = document.getElementById('granite_new');
        var options = first.innerHTML;
        var second = document.getElementById('granite_selector');

        // REPLACE VALUES
        second.innerHTML = options;

        // CHANGE CABINET IMAGE TO BE IN THE COLLECTION OF CHOICE
        changeGranite("granite_selector");
    } else if (document.getElementById("granite_collection").value == "Specialty Styles") {
        // COPY VALUES
        var first = document.getElementById('specialty_granite_styles');
        var options = first.innerHTML;
        var second = document.getElementById('granite_selector');

        // REPLACE VALUES
        second.innerHTML = options;

        // CHANGE CABINET IMAGE TO BE IN THE COLLECTION OF CHOICE
        changeGranite("granite_selector");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm viewing your example in IE 10 and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `.innerHTML` in general; it's using it with `<select>` elements that's causing you problems. There are a couple ways to solve the problem. A simple one is to replace the entire `<select>` element along with the option list. That is, if your HTML looks like this:

```
<select name=whatever id=whatever>
  <option value=1>Hello
  <option value=2>World
</select>
```

Then you could alter that to be:

```
<span class=select-wrapper>
  <select name=whatever id=whatever>
    <option value=1>Hello
    <option value=2>World
  </select>
</span>
```

Then just replace the `.innerHTML` of the `<span>` wrapper around the `<select>`.

The other way to solve the problem is to build an array of Option instances and update the "options" property of the `<select>` element.

Comment: Thanks! I did an array and simplified my functions. Now there is one function for changing the image and another for populating the fields using new option arrays. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of why you would have problems with IE7+, I don't have nay Microsoft products  to test with but maybe this bug:

[BUG: Internet Explorer Fails to Set the innerHTML Property of the Select Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228)

But taking @Pointy answer, then you could perform a replace of the select like this, rather than wrap the element, uses [`Node.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) [`Node.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild). I believe this is cross-browser.

HTML

```
<select name="granite_collection" id="granite_collection">
    <option selected="selected">Choose a Collection</option>
    <option value="new_arrivals">Granite: New Arrivals</option>
    <option value="Specialty Styles">Granite: Specialty Styles</option>
</select>
<select name="granite_selector" id="granite_selector"></select>
<select name="cabinet_style" id="cabinet_style" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Brandy wine.jpg">Brandy Wine</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Canvas.jpg">Canvas</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Country Linen.jpg">Country Linen</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Expresso.jpg">Expresso</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Mocha glazed.jpg">Mocha Glazed</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Shaker.jpg">Shaker</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Tahoe.jpg">Tahoe</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Charleston Antique White.jpg">Charleston Antique White</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Charleston Cherry.jpg">Charleston Cherry</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Charleston Saddle.jpg">Charleston Saddle</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Java Shaker.jpg">Java Shaker</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Savannah Toffee.jpg">Savannah Toffee</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/White Shaker.jpg">White Shaker</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/York Chocolate.jpg">York Chocolate</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/York Antique White.jpg">York Antique White</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Dillon1.jpg">Dillon1</option>
    <option value="images/doorstyles/Dillon2.jpg">Dillon2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var graniteCollection = document.getElementById("granite_collection"),
    graniteSelector = document.getElementById("granite_selector"),
    cabinetStyle = document.getElementById("cabinet_style");

graniteCollection.onchange = function () {
    var clone = cabinetStyle.cloneNode(true);

    clone.id = graniteSelector.id;
    clone.name = graniteSelector.name;
    clone.style.visibility = "";
    graniteSelector.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, graniteSelector);
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/SGkay/)